# Dualizing sheaf on singular curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, residue-calculus, algebraic-curves

I am trying to understand two points brought up in Harris and Morrison's moduli of Curves, but I would like to have a more general understanding than simply considering nodal curves. So let $C$ be a complete algebraic curve over an algebraically closed field $k$, with a singular point $p$ and $\nu: \tilde{C} \rightarrow C$ the normalization, and $\pi^{-1}(p)=\{q_1, \dots q_i\}.$

Harris and Morrison say "the dualizing sheaf $\omega_C$ associates to each $U \subset C$ the rational one-forms $\eta$ on $\nu^{-1}(U) \subset \tilde{C}$ such that for each $p \in U$ and each $f \in \mathscr{O}_{C, p}$, $$\sum_{q \in \nu^{-1}(p)} Res_q(\nu^*(f) \cdot \eta)=0. $$

My first question is 1): how do we prove this?

Naively following what Emerton presented here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58559/dualizing-sheaf-of-a-nodal-curve?rq=1, I would first try the following. We might have a short exact sequence $$ 0 \rightarrow \nu_*\Omega_{\tilde{C}} \rightarrow \nu_*\Omega_{\tilde{C}}(\sum q_j) \rightarrow  (k_p)^i \rightarrow 0.$$

In the nodal case, Emerton can then relate $\omega_C$ to a subsheaf of $\nu_*(\Omega_{\tilde{C}}(\sum q_j))$.
However I worry that I am already wrong (in the worse-than-nodal case): it seems like I am assuming that $\omega_C$ consists of sections which have at most simple poles at preimages of the singular point. Could someone help me a little, either by telling me that this short exact sequence is correct or correcting me if it is not the case?

My second question 2) is more simple and naive: Harris and Morrison claim that the above condition on the residues is sufficient, in the nodal case, to show that only simple poles are possible.  However I do not see this; why may I not have a rational one-form $\eta$ with poles of order 2 at each preimage $q_1$ and $q_2$ with 0 residue at each point, thus satisfying the condition?

My overall hunch is that the residue theorem for complete algebraic curves, despite only mentioning residues, actually provides control over possible higher order poles, but I don't understand how. Insight here would help me with both questions.

Comment: What you've quoted for (1) is just the definition. Is your question how we show that this deserves to be called the dualizing sheaf? This is outlined as Exercise 3.8 in H&M. The idea is to use Serre Duality on the normalization to show that "pushforward of the sheaf of rational..." construction does what a dualizing sheaf is supposed to do (they also indicate that Hartshorne's *Residues and Duality* has a proof)....

Comment: ...I don't recall how to do (2) at the moment, but it's outlined in Problem 2 of these notes (https://www.math.colostate.edu/~renzo/teaching/Topics10/Psibelow.pdf) which suggest that it's a local concern, not a consequence of the global residue theorem.

Comment: This is Theorem 5.2.3 in Conrad's *Grothendieck Duality and Base Change*.